# Can't run SQL query due to type conversion failure, key violation, and more

Tags: sql, ms-access

I get an error when trying to run this SQL query in MS Access:

```
INSERT INTO Learner (learnerPersonIDPKFK, registrationDate)
VALUES (1, 21/09/2015);

INSERT INTO Learner (learnerPersonIDPKFK, registrationDate, recommendedByLearnerPersonIDFK)
VALUES (2, 05/03/2016, 1);
```

This is the error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUEu8.png)

The `Learner` table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Learner
(
      learnerPersonIDPKFK INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      registrationDate DATETIME,
      recommendedByLearnerPersonIDFK INT NOT NULL,

      CONSTRAINT fk_recommendedByLearnerPersonIDFK
          FOREIGN KEY(recommendedByLearnerPersonIDFK)
          REFERENCES Learner (learnerPersonIDPKFK)
);
```

Comment: Date constants need to be surrounded by single quotes (in most databases) or `#` in MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your dates in single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO Learner (learnerPersonIDPKFK, registrationDate)
    VALUES (1, '21/09/2015');
INSERT INTO Learner (learnerPersonIDPKFK, registrationDate, recommendedByLearnerPersonIDFK)
    VALUES (2, '05/03/2016', 1);
```

Depending on your localization settings for the DATETIME format, you may need to use the MM/DD/YYYY format. Remember, your passing in a varchar and letting SQL try to "guess" how to implicitly convert it:

```
INSERT INTO Learner (learnerPersonIDPKFK, registrationDate)
    VALUES (1, '09/21/2015');
INSERT INTO Learner (learnerPersonIDPKFK, registrationDate, recommendedByLearnerPersonIDFK)
    VALUES (2, '03/05/2016', 1);
```

Use a simple tester to verify if SQL can "guess" your date formating:

```
SELECT CAST('09/21/2015' AS DATETIME)
```